# How to access extension's local storage from a blocking onBeforeSendHeaders webRequest hook?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, webrequest

My extension is an MV2 chrome extension.
I need to access a value stored in the extension's local storage from within a blocking webRequest hook (MV2 [chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/)).

Since it is blocking, the listener must not be async.
How can I access the extension's local storage inside the hook?

I tried to use the window object to sync it with the local storage and then access it inside the listener, but it is too flaky and bad practice.

Comment: Use `localStorage` instead of chrome.storage.local.

Comment: @wOxxOm is it best practice to always keep `localStorage` in sync with `chrome.storage.local`? Or should I only use it for the keys needed in the blocking webRequest hooks?

Comment: If the data is small it should be fine to use localStorage.